# "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" for a Range Limit

Tags: swift, generics

Note: there are a few other questions about "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" - for example this one [Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157253/generic-parameter-t-could-not-be-inferred) - but none of them are related to *Range* limits.

Consider this code:

```
 (0..<10).map{ }
```

Why is this causing the aforementioned error?

[image]

Does the compiler want some "help" on determining the types ?  If so what is the syntax?

Comment: Closure types are only automatically inferred for *single expression closures,” compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42534207/1187415

Comment: @MartinR I was just about to share the same exact question! What a coincidence!

Comment: A simple example: `let foo = (0..<10).map { Float($0) }` compiles, but `let bar = (0..<10).map { let out = Float($0); return out }` does not.

Comment: `var sineWave = (0..<10).map { y -> Float in
            let out = sin(2.0 * Float.pi * Float(y))
            return out
        }`

Comment: @udbhateja Thanks for that help on the syntax: please feel free to add an answer and i'll upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comments from @MartinR and @Sweeper it is easy enough to understand and fix the problem *once it was made clear *where* the error actually lies* .  `Xcode` has highlighted the wrong place (see OP).

```
let sineWave: [Float] = (0..<10).map {
            let out: Float = amplitude * sin(2.0 * .pi * Float($0) / Float(sampleFreq))
            return out
    }
```

Note that the problem is on the `return type` of the *overall closure* *not* on the `Range(0..<10)`  .

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but does `sinewave` really need to be mutable? Unless you mutate it later on, it should be immutable.

Comment: Sure it was originally a `let` - and should be reverted to same. i was trying all sorts of things to figure out what were happening here ;) .  Just fixed it back now.

Comment: @javadba you don't even need to set the resulting type explicitly as long as you have a single expression `let sineWave = (0..<10).map { amplitude * sin(2.0 * .pi * Float($0) / Float(sampleFreq))
}`

Answer (score 1):

The construct

```
   y -> Float in
```

can be used to provide the necessary hints to the compiler:

```
    var sineWave = (0..<10).map { y -> Float in
        let out = amplitude * sin(2.0 * .pi * Float(y) / Float(sampleFreq))
        return out
    }
```